# Terraform Import azurerm_role_assignment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have to import some roles, in the documentation it states.
The frist uid is easy to find, but what is the second one.
When I look into the portal I see that the role is assigned on the resource itself, but can't find a trace of a uid. Can find the uid of the group what has the rights but ..

```
terraform import azurerm_role_assignment.example /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

So Bottom line, anybody has this working and willing to share some thoughts ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure CLI:

```
az role assignment list ...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az-role-assignment-list

Comment: For example : `az role assignment list --query '[].{name:name, roleDefinintionName:roleDefinitionName principalType:principalType, principalName:principalName, scope:scope}' -o table`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) portal to browse your resource definitions.

Use the tree view on the left to browse your resources; generally the structure's pretty intuitive.

To avoid clicking through, the URIs are pretty predictable too...

- To see role assignments against a subscription substitute your subscription's GUID in the following URI: [https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments](https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments)
- To do the same for a resource group, substitute your subscription's GUID and resource group's name for the placeholder values in this URI: [https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`/resourceGroups/`MyResourceGroup`/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments](https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments)

Note: If you paste in one of these URIs directly it takes a few moments for the right page to load / the page may refresh a few times, so if you don't see the page you'd expect, wait up to 10 seconds.

On this page, you'll see a JSON value, where the info you're after is under `value` > `properties` > `id`.

Comment: the Azure Resource Explorer link saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Azure**

If you have defined your resource similar to this:

```
resource "azuread_app_role_assignment" "role_assignment" {
   principal_object_id = azuread_service_principal.service_principal.object_id
   resource_object_id = azuread_application.api_test.object_id
   app_role_id = azuread_application.api_test.app_role.*.id[0]
}
```

Then run following PowerShell script in order to retrieve assignment id  (and relative path) for import:

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId "[YourTenantId]" -Scopes Application.Read.All

$yourServicePrincipalObjectId = "[ServicePrincipalObjectId]"
$appRoleId = "[AppRoleId]"

$assignments = Get-MgServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment -ServicePrincipalId $yourServicePrincipalObjectId
$desiredAssignment = $assignments | Where-Object { $_.AppRoleId -eq $appRoleId }

$AssignmetPath = $desiredAssignment.ResourceId + "/appRoleAssignment/" + $desiredAssignment.Id

Write-Host $AssignmetPath
```

After that, get $AssignmentPath value, replace it with the placeholder below and run the command under to import role assignment (per version 2.38.0).

`terraform import azuread_app_role_assignment.role_assignment Insert_AssignmentPath_Value_Here`